# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" when import Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

When I try to import Firebase to my javascript project

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This error comes up

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {getDatabase} from 'firebase/database';
```

Thats my code

I want to import it in my chrome extension

Comment: You need a bundler like webpack, snowpack, or vite (many more exist) to be able to import things, especially npm packages, in a chrome extension